# How to set variables for schedule in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a scheduled pipeline in GitLab CI/CD and need to set value of VARIABLE

For that I added under Schedule Variables:

[image]

and also updated YAML File with:

```
 script:
    - set VARIABLE=${VARIABLE}
    - echo ${VARIABLE}
    - mvn clean test -D"VARIABLE=${VARIABLE}"
```

But still old value of VARIABLE was taken.
What I should do else?

Comment: You’re supposed to set the value of the variable in the schedules section and then use that variable. I don’t understand why you would go to the trouble to set up a variable in a schedule and then try to set up another.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. If I set a variable in a schedule, when the scheduled pipeline runs, the variable has the value set in pipeline schedules (as expected according to [variable precedence](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence).) There must be something else happening here in your case, but the important details don't appear to be present in the question. We need more details.